# Reformatting a list in R

Tags: r

I have a list of my results in R in the format:

```
Result:
Cat1
Cat2
Cat1
Cat3
...
```

I need to get it into the format:

```
Results:
        ....Cat 1.....Cat 2.....Cat3
            1         0         0
            0         1         0
            1         0         0
            0         0         1
```

I know this is a basic question, but without knowing the terms to search for I am having a very difficult time finding an answer. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: It may be "basic" but I cannot figure out what the starting point might be so It's also vague. Are you trying to make a contingency table? Post some data with dput or create some with code and we'll be better able to assist.

Comment: I am trying to predict the category of crimes committed. My predictions are currently in a list like the one above, but I need them to be in a matrix form. I would be happy to post pictures if you think they would help, but there are 800,000 entries with 39 options for categories so it does not seem very helpful to visualize.

Comment: Sounds like you want a contingency table. The `table` function seems sufficient if you just want to count categorical values.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need `model.matrix`

```
model.matrix(~0+Category, df1)
#  CategoryCat1 CategoryCat2 CategoryCat3
#1            1            0            0
#2            0            1            0
#3            1            0            0
#4            0            0            1
#attr(,"assign")
#[1] 1 1 1
#attr(,"contrasts")
#attr(,"contrasts")$Category
#[1] "contr.treatment"
```

Or use `table`

```
table(1:nrow(df1), df1$Category)

#     Cat1 Cat2 Cat3
#  1    1    0    0
#  2    0    1    0
#  3    1    0    0
#  4    0    0    1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Category = c("Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat1", "Cat3")),
.Names = "Category", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```